# #define macro doesn't print variable

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#define PRINT(fmt, ...) printf("%s:%d: "fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__, ##  __VA_ARGS__)
```

It works well when I pass some value to it, eg `PRINT("Hello, world").`
But when I pass variable as an argument, eg. `PRINT(somevar)` it doesn't print the value of variable `int somevar`. How should I rewrite the macros to make it print variables as well?

Comment: You mean I have better to rewrite it as a conventional routine and use va_list?

Comment: The macro will _not_ work unless the `fmt` (first) argument to the macro can be concatenated with the `"%s:%d: "` string, which means it too must be a literal.  To print `int somevar`, the macro invocation must be `PRINT("%d\n", somevar);`.

Comment: In short, you can't invoke `printf` as `printf(some_int_var)` either; a format string is needed. This is no different (and in fact mandatory as a const-literal, as your logic now mandates it as concat-able, and a computed format string is not feasible, fair warning). The only immediate you can get away with sending to this is just like `printf`, a `char*`  (const or otherwise) itself, and just like `printf` that would be discouraged for security reasons.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that link is *stellar*. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't in the macro.   It is in how you use it.   Essentially, your usage requires you to use PRINT with a format string, which must be a string literal that describes what to do with the subsequent arguments.

For example, try

```
PRINT("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
```

where `x` and `y` are variables of type `int`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  and Rob. Terrific!! You have solved my problem in no time at all!!